# Simplest way to add a new PHP Class and have access to it everywhere in my Laravel 4 App Without using Composer?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an ACL Class in my PHP LAravel 4 app in which I need to have access to in pretty much any route, view, etc...

How can I get it to be autoloaded and access it in the Laravel App?

A;; the Composer stuff for the autoloading confuses me and also when the app was built all the composer commands were ran on a PC and then the app simply uploaded to the LAMP server.  So the server does not even have composer installed.

Is there a way to do this without installing and running composer?  Obviously without manually including the new Class in every file it is needed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to autoload a single file.

Edit `vendor/composer/autoload_files.php` and add your single file there.

`$baseDir` is the folder 'vendor'

```
<?php

// autoload_files.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    $vendorDir . '/location/ofmy/file.php',
);
```

---

If you'd like to persist this change if someone else runs composer in the future, add a `files` section inside `autoload` in your composer.json

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
  "require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.0.10"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app/commands",
      "app/controllers",
      "app/models"
    ],
    "files": [
      "location/ofmy/file.php" <-- this guy right here
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: I see so this is basically like manually doing what Composer would of done had I done it the common way using composer right?  If so, very cool I have wanted to know how to do that for a while now.  Also if thats true, lets say someday the composer commands are ran that regenerate all this stuff, I would lose my manual edits or no?  Thanks

Comment: You would indeed lose your manual edits. Check the edit for instructions on how to not lose those. Cheers!

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks this is a very useful bookmarkable answer, might even be valuable enough to share with my followers, thank you!

Comment: I noticed you removed the namespace file part, is that of no use now?

Comment: It was only useful if you wanted to include an entire namespace worth of files.